# Unit test throwing an exception while connecting to asp.net web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, integration-testing

I created a unit test to test if a I can login to my ASP.NET web service. The web service works fine and even the login process.

However when trying to connect to it through my test it is giving me an error:

> The URL specified ('http://www.foo.com/') does not correspond to
>   a valid directory. Tests configured to run in ASP.NET in IIS require a
>   valid directory to exist for the URL.

I'm running my web service through visual studio, since the project is still in development.

this is my test code:

```
[TestMethod()]
        [HostType("ASP.NET")]
        [UrlToTest("http://www.foo.com/")]
        public void Login_Test_It_Fails_If_GUID_IS_Wrong()
        {
            //Arrange
            Service service = new Service(); 
            string pGUID = string.Empty; 
            string connectionSQL = @"XXXXXXXXXX";
            bool targetOutput = false;

            //Act
            targetOutput = service.Login(pGUID, connectionSQL);

            //Assert
            Assert.IsFalse(targetOutput);
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's connecting to a web service it's not a unit test, it's an integration test. If you're just testing the logic of the Login method you should extract the logic to another class (that you can inject into the service) and unit test that class without instantiating the service.

Comment: Should unit tests really be doing integration tests?

Comment: Yes you're right it shouldn't, I'm quite new to Unit testing/Integration testing, actually this is my firs experiment. I'm familiar with the theory although I've never actually implemented any test cases. However, let's say this was an integration test. Why isn't it working ?

Comment: I don't know. I suspect that it is either security (since unit tests usually run in their own directory and thread) or network settings. Does it work if you point it at localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing an *integration test* here, as you are testing that your application can communicate with an external dependency.

If you wanted to unit test, you might want to explore a different approach.

1. If the web service is something you control, you can write tests for the service itself confirming its login authentication logic.
2. For your consuming application, you can write unit tests based off of a *mock* of the service to ensure that your application exhibits the correct behavior when it receives a response from the service.

On another note, passing the connection string to use into the service seems like a poor design. Why should the calling application need to have any knowledge of what database the service should be using?

Comment: Hmm ... I'll look more into integration testing then. About the connection string, that's the first thing I said when I saw this design, however this way we can control to which database the client can connect to if there are multiple databases. (long story short)

Answer (score 0):

Running tests in ASP.NET requires the URL to resolve to an ASP.NET page and for the page to execute properly up to the Load event.
The test method is called by page load event. So, you can create a blank aspx page, and set the UrlToTest attribute to hook it.